# Back-calculation of the minimum sample size for an mechanical experiment

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, sample-size, extreme-value

I want to back-calculate the minimum sample size for an experiment.
I have a known mean and standard variance of a statistical population. From the statistical population I chose two samples with means and standard deviations I could estimate.
My question is: How can I calculate a theoretical sampling size based on the means and variances of the samples considering a confidence interval of 2σ.

**Update**:
I have done a comparative study where I compare the material strenghts of different groups of a material. I can calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the groups. The question is whether the differences in strength of the material groups are significant or not. So I want to calculate the minimum number of samples and compare the minimum number of samples to my already measured number of samples. I want to make a statistical significant testimony. If the difference is not statistically significant I would have to change my interpretation.

Comment: Because you know the mean and variance, what's the purpose of the experiment?  Why take any samples at all?  What are you trying to test or estimate?

Comment: I have done a comparative study where I compare the material strenghts of different groups of a material. I can calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the groups. The question is if the differences in strength of the material groups are significant or not. So I want to calculate the minimum number of samples and compare the minimum number of samples to my already measured number of samples. I want to make a statistical significant testimony. If the difference is not statistically significant I would have to change my interpretation.